# Getting a console.log from http.post data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get a console log of the concatenated url, I have tried to create a new variable and then pass this to console.log with no success.

How can I get a log of the url I trying to post?

```
        $scope.sendPaymentConfirmation = function (ordernumber) {
        //function sendPaymentConfirmation(ordernumber) {
            $http({
                url: ('http://example.com/api/' + ordernumber), //'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
                var posturl = url;
                console.log(posturl);
                method: "POST",
                //data: postData,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .then(function(response) {
                    // success : Thankyou, payment confirmation has been sent to the API server
                    window.alert('SUCCESS - Payment confirmation has been sent to the API server');
                }, 
                function(response) { // optional
                    // failed : ERROR There has been an error sending payment confirmation to the API server
                    window.alert('ERROR - There has been an error sending payment confirmation to the API server');
                }
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that object literals cannot have statements and semicolons in them. If you don't want to do it the standard way @Quentin suggested, then you can do it like this (immediate function invocation):

```
    $http({
            url: (function(){
                  var posturl = 'http://example.com/api/' + ordernumber; //'http://samedomain.com/GetPersons',
                  console.log(posturl);
                  return posturl;
            })(),
            method: "POST",
            //data: postData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a variable inside an object literal. Nor can you put any other arbitrary JS statements there.

Create the variable first. Then use it later.

```
var posturl = 'http://example.com/api/' + ordernumber
console.log(posturl);

$http({
     url: posturl,
```